# Hover not working in JQuery

Tags: html, jquery

I created a simple DIV, which is located on the edge of the page, and I wrote this, a simple script that moves it.

The problem is that when you hover the mouse over a DIV, and then take your cursor. When DIV hides and again move the cursor to the DIV, then the script all the time, ejects and hide DIV.

I created for you, "Fiddle", in jsFiddle.com to better illustrate my problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/IdolwSzutrab7/DWvbJ/, and an animated gif that shows the problem:

```
$('#h53pg4s4b6').hover(function () {
    $('#h53pg4s4b6').delay(400).animate({
        right: "3px"
    }, 1300);
    $('#u26c5lsx9h').animate({
        opacity: "1.0"
    }, 500);
    clearTimeout(time3);
}, function () {
    time3 = setTimeout(function () {
        $('#h53pg4s4b6').animate({
            right: "-220px"
        }, 1300);
        $('#u26c5lsx9h').delay(1400).animate({
            opacity: "0.2"
        }, 500);
    }, 1000)
})

 $('#t895o6n9qs').click(function () {
    $('#b37jjlmy2t').css('display', 'block');
    $('#a15tnjlyw6').css('display', 'none');
})

 $('#u83mz78d5l').click(function () {
    $('#b37jjlmy2t').css('display', 'none');
    $('#a15tnjlyw6').css('display', 'block');
})

 $('#s4iu2h7dra').click(function () {
    $('#h53pg4s4b6').fadeOut(3000, function () {
        $('#h53pg4s4b6').remove();
    });
})
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxVDK.gif]

How to ...

How to stop the script?

Or not ...

I do not know ...

Maybe I should write another script?

I do not know what I can do about it :/

▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬

Please, can you help me?

PS: Sorry for my english, I hope you understood me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery `.stop()` will help you here

See the updated [**JSFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/DWvbJ/26/)

I updated your code as follows

```
$('#h53pg4s4b6').hover(function () {
    $('#u26c5lsx9h').stop().animate({
        opacity: "1.0"
    }, 500, function () {
        $('#h53pg4s4b6').stop().animate({
            right: "3px"
        }, 1300);
    });
    clearTimeout(time3);
}, function () {
    time3 = setTimeout(function () {
        $('#h53pg4s4b6').stop().animate({
            right: "-220px"
        }, 1300);
        $('#u26c5lsx9h').stop().animate({
            opacity: "0.2"
        }, 500);
    }, 1000)
})
```

Also, I have one suggestion: You may remove the delay() functions since the effect will be more smooth without those.

Comment: Thank you!
It works perfectly :)
But, the delay() was slow animation to the first DIV opacity 1.0, and then slide. Now this DIV slide and changes the opacity at the same time :(

Comment: Delay() is not the right choice for that. Updated my answer and fiddle. check it..

Comment: Ohh... Ok... I understand. It is quite complicated, so I will not take for the delay.

Comment: Finally, I did something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/IdolwSzutrab7/DWvbJ/28/ Thank you for any suggestions and help, I greet!